# Sending telemetry data to Thingsboard server with Python - Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, api, http-status-code-404, thingsboard, telemetry

I'm trying to send telemetry data to ThingsBoard using the API, but I'm encountering a 401 error code when making the request. I'm using the following Python script, but I can't seem to resolve the issue. Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong?

```
import requests
import time
import json

server = "https://demo.thingsboard.io"
access_token = "Qk78CWpafxj4NB2TzGXz"
entity_id = "f6fa1e60-a078-11ed-bed1-3ba75184734b"

def send_active(server, access_token, entity_id, msg):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    url = f"{server}/api/v1/{entity_id}/telemetry"
    payload = {
        "ts": int(time.time() * 1000),
        "values": {
            "message": msg
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    if response.status_code != 204:
        print("Request headers:", response.request.headers)
        print("Request body:", response.request.body)
        print("Request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response content:", response.content)
        raise Exception("Failed to send telemetry data")

msg = "active"
send_active(server, access_token, entity_id, msg)
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Request headers: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.27.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer Qk78CWpafxj4NB2TzGXz', 'Content-Length': '51'}
Request body: b'{"ts": 1676028720, "values": {"message": "active"}}'
Request failed with status code: 401
Response content: b''
```

Comment: When I am stuck in problems with APIs, I always go to Postman and poke around there with my configuration. It's harder to see problem in code then it is in GUI that's specialized for testing APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If `access_token` is a token of your device (not user), then do this:

```
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    url = f"{server}/api/v1/{access_token}/telemetry"
    payload = {
        "ts": int(time.time() * 1000),
        "values": {
            "message": msg
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```